# Contextual Action Bar with RecyclerView in xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin.android

Can any one tell  how to implement RecyclerView Contextual Action Bar on long tap of listItem Selection on xamarin android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can any one tell how to implement RecyclerView Contextual Action Bar on long tap of listItem Selection on xamarin android?

Take [Xamarin Official RecyclerViewer](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/RecyclerViewer/) for example, you can follow the below steps to implement a contextual action bar on the recyclerview:

1. Create a simple menu resource for your action bar(`Resource/menu/ContextualMenu`):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/itemOneId"
       android:title="Item One"/>
     <item android:id="@+id/itemTwoId"
       android:title="Item Two" />
   </menu>
   ```
2. Create a class(`MyActionMode`) implements `ActionMode.ICallBack`:

   ```
   public class MyActionMode : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
   {
       private Context mContext;
       public MyActionMode(Context context)
       {
           mContext = context;
       }

       public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
       {
           switch (item.ItemId)
           {
               case Resource.Id.itemOneId:
                   // do whatever you want
                   return true;
               case Resource.Id.itemTwoId:
                   // do whatever you want
                   return true;
               default:
                   return false;
           }
       }

       public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
       {
           mode.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.ContextualMenu, menu);
           return true;
       }

       public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
       {
           mode.Dispose();
       }

       public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
3. In `PhotoViewHolder` modify the constructor to accept a long click action:

   ```
   public PhotoViewHolder (View itemView, Action<int> listener,Action<object,View.LongClickEventArgs> longClickListener) 
       : base (itemView)
   {
       // Locate and cache view references:
       Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView);
       Caption = itemView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView);

       // Detect user clicks on the item view and report which item
       // was clicked (by position) to the listener:
       itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener (base.Position);
       ItemView.LongClick +=(sender,e)=> longClickListener(sender,e);
   }
   ```
4. Modify `PhotoAlbumAdapter` like this:

   ```
   public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
   {
       ...
       // add this variable
       private Activity mActivity;

       //
       private MyActionMode mActionMode;

       ...
       // add this constructor
       public PhotoAlbumAdapter(PhotoAlbum photoAlbum, Activity activity)
       {
           mPhotoAlbum = photoAlbum;
           mActivity = activity;
       }


       //add this function
       void OnLongClick(object sender, View.LongClickEventArgs args)
       {
           mActionMode = new MyActionMode(mActivity);
           mActivity.StartActionMode(mActionMode);
           ((View)sender).Selected = true;
           return;
       }
      ...
   }
   ```
5. In `MainActivity` change the creation of `PhotoAlbumAdapter` to use the newly created constructor:

   ```
   mAdapter = new PhotoAlbumAdapter (mPhotoAlbum,this);
   ```

Here is the [complete modified demo](https://github.com/elvisxia/RecyclerViewer).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation,your answer solved my issues and thanks a lot for answering @ right time :)

Comment: Xia  Can you tell me how to delete recyclerview list item from contextual button action?

Comment: You can open another question about that, so that everyone can find it through google.

Comment: Xia i have posted the question at the give link https://stackoverflow.com/q/45929315/6117355