# The RecyclerView item click on xamarin android is not working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello everyone my name is Taniguchi and i created a recyclerview and i want to create i click listener to show an contextual action bar according to this documentation [Contextual Action Bar with RecyclerView in xamarin android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897288/contextual-action-bar-with-recyclerview-in-xamarin-android) but its not working, when i click a item on recyclerview nothing happens.

my click listener:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, View.IOnClickListener, View.IOnLongClickListener
    {

        public TextView mName;
        public TextView mSubject;
        public TextView mMessage;
        private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            mName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            mSubject = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            mMessage = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            itemView.SetOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.SetOnLongClickListener(this);
        }
        public void SetItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener)
        {
            this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
        }

        public bool OnLongClick(View v)
        {
            itemClickListener.OnClick(v, AdapterPosition, true);
            return true;
        }

        public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            itemClickListener.OnClick(v, AdapterPosition, false);
        }
    }
```

The click listener interface:

```
 public interface ItemClickListener
{
    void OnClick(View itemView, int position, bool isLongClick);
}
```

The class to create to contextual action bar:

```
public class MyActionMode : Java.Lang.Object, ActionMode.ICallback
{
    private Context mContext;
    public MyActionMode(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public bool OnActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.itemOneId:
                // do whatever you want
                return true;
            case Resource.Id.itemTwoId:
                // do whatever you want
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public bool OnCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        mode.MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.ContextualMenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void OnDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
    {
        mode.Dispose();
    }

    public bool OnPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, IMenu menu)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

MyRecyclerView Class

```
public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, ItemClickListener
    {
        // add this variable

        private Activity mActivity;
        private MyActionMode mActionMode;
        private List<Email> mEmails;
        private Context context;
        public RecyclerAdapter (List<Email> emails, Context context)
        {
            mEmails = emails;
            this.context = context;
        }
        public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public View mMainView { get; set; }
            public TextView mName { get; set; }
            public TextView mSubject { get; set; }
            public TextView mMessage { get; set; }

            public MyView (View view) : base(view)
            {
                mMainView = view;
            }


        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return mEmails.Count; }
        }



        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            RecyclerViewHolder vh = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
            MyView myHolder = holder as MyView;
            myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[position].Name;
            myHolder.mSubject.Text = mEmails[position].Subject;
            myHolder.mMessage.Text = mEmails[position].Message;

        }

        public void OnClick(View itemView, int position, bool isLongClick)
        {
            if (isLongClick)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Long Click : " + mEmails[position], ToastLength.Short).Show();

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Long Click : " + mEmails[position], ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
            TextView txtName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            TextView txtSubject = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            TextView txtMessage = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);

            MyView view = new MyView(row) { mName = txtName, mSubject = txtSubject, mMessage = txtMessage };
            return view;
        }

    }
```

when i Call the recyclerview:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {   //set our view from the Main  layout Resource
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerViwer);
        mRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
        SetupList();


        //Create our layout Manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        RecyclerAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mEmails,this);
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    private void SetupList()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            mEmails = new List<Email>();
            mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
            mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
            mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
            mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
            mEmails.Add(new Email() { Name = "tom", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try creating a View.IOnClickListener that is NOT your viewHolder object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MyView view = new MyView(row) { mName = txtName, mSubject =
>   txtSubject, mMessage = txtMessage };

you have customized `RecyclerViewHolder` ，you could use it directly.
if you use `MyView` , in the class,no click events are defined.so you should do like this:

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder (row);
        viewHolder .SetItemClickListener(this);
        return viewHolder ;
    }

public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;
        myHolder.mName.Text = mEmails[position].Name;
        myHolder.mSubject.Text = mEmails[position].Subject;
        myHolder.mMessage.Text = mEmails[position].Message;

    }
```